# Flask Admin two admin panels

Tags: python, flask-admin

I'm trying to create two separate admin pages that behaves differently.
I've successfully made two separate admin pages working but I can't seem to figure out how I can set the AdminIndexView for second admin page.

```
class FlaskAdminIndexView(AdminIndexView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        if not current_user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(url_for('security.login'))
        elif (current_user.is_authenticated) and (not current_user.has_role('first_admin')):
            return redirect(url_for('post_user.index_entry'))
        else:
            return super(FlaskAdminIndexView, self).index()

first_admin = flask_admin.Admin(app, 'RCIGM ADMIN', base_template='my_master.html', 
                          template_mode='bootstrap3',
                          index_view=FlaskAdminIndexView())
```

Above code snippet is how I set the user accessibility to first admin page.

```
class FlaskSecondAdminIndexView(AdminIndexView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        if not current_user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(url_for('security.login'))
        elif (current_user.is_authenticated) and (not current_user.has_role('second_admin')):
            return redirect(url_for('post_user.index_entry'))
        else:
            return self.render('admin/base.html')
            #return super(FlaskAdminIndexView, self).index()

second_admin = flask_admin.Admin(app, 'SITE ADMIN', url='/site_admin', 
                           base_template='my_master.html', endpoint='site_admin',
                           template_mode='bootstrap3', index_view=FlaskSecondAdminIndexView())
```

The above code snippet is for my second admin page, and I get blueprint collision error like below.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/genom003dm/PycharmProjects/sample_accessioning_dev/app/run.py", line 2, in <module>
        from app import app
      File "/Users/genom003dm/PycharmProjects/sample_accessioning_dev/app/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
        from app.views.post_inputs import post_user_blueprint
      File "/Users/genom003dm/PycharmProjects/sample_accessioning_dev/app/views/post_inputs.py", line 65, in <module>
        from app.security_layer import generate_registration_token, confirm_token, user_datastore, \
      File "/Users/genom003dm/PycharmProjects/sample_accessioning_dev/app/security_layer.py", line 249, in <module>
        template_mode='bootstrap3', index_view=FlaskSecondAdminIndexView())
      File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 522, in __init__
        self._set_admin_index_view(index_view=index_view, endpoint=endpoint, url=url)
      File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 566, in _set_admin_index_view
        self.add_view(self.index_view)
      File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 540, in add_view
        self.app.register_blueprint(view.create_blueprint(self))
      File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 64, in wrapper_func
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/genom003dm/sample_accessioning_dev_virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 946, in register_blueprint
        (blueprint, self.blueprints[blueprint.name], blueprint.name)
    AssertionError: A blueprint's name collision occurred between <flask.blueprints.Blueprint object at 0x104f95a20> and <flask.blueprints.Blueprint object at 0x104e500b8>.  Both share the same name "admin".  Blueprints that are created on the fly need unique names.
```

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `url` and `endpoint` when the `AdminIndexView` are created.

For example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_admin import Admin, expose, AdminIndexView


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '''
        <a href="/first-admin/">Click me to get to First Admin!</a><br>
        <a href="/second-admin/">Click me to get to Second Admin!</a>
        '''


class FirstAdminIndexView(AdminIndexView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        return 'Hello From first admin :{}.'.format(self)


class SecondAdminIndexView(AdminIndexView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        return 'Hello From second admin :{}'.format(self)


first_admin = Admin(
    app,
    template_mode="bootstrap3",
    url='/first-admin',
    endpoint='first',
    index_view=FirstAdminIndexView(url='/first-admin', endpoint='first')
)


second_admin = Admin(
    app,
    template_mode="bootstrap3",
    url='/second-admin',
    endpoint='second',
    index_view=SecondAdminIndexView(url='/second-admin', endpoint='second')
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```