# Flask Admin multiple admin pages

Tags: flask, flask-admin

Is there a way to create multiple admin pages using Flask admin library. For example, I have 2 user role ( Admin, Manager). I want these two user roles to have access to the admin page(using Flask admin) but viewing and editing different information. A name collision between Blueprint errors shows up, when I try to run Flask admin twice.

[image]

Comment: I answered a similar question a while back,  [Flask Admin two admin panels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44718068/2800058).

Answer (score 0):

For avoiding collisions you can use the `endpoint` param when *adding your views*.

Let's say you have two classes `AdminModelView` and `ManagerModelView`. They both extend [BaseModelView](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/) and take as first positional argument the same model (e.g. `Model`).

Under these assumptions you can do something like this:

```
...
admin.add_view(AdminModelView(Model, ..., endpoint="admin"))
admin.add_view(ManagerModelView(Model, ..., endpoint="manager"))
...
```

where `admin` is an instance of `Admin` from `flask_admin`.